# Convert JPG files to video

Tags: video, jpg, converter

from a trail camera we have many JPG files, that was shot in every 5 mins about a construction.

We have Ubuntu + Win10 desktops.

What should we use to convert the JPG files to different FPS videos? Ex.: few frames per sec, isn't an issue that it is not 24/sec.

**Q:** Any solution can come handy, but which is recommended? (ex.: maybe preferred free/legal softwares and on Ubuntu!)

Answer (score 1):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) can do that (free, open source, cross-platform, has official Ubuntu packages). Assuming you have a folder full of JPG files named like "img043251.jpg", "img043252.jpg" and so on, something like this would convert them into a video:

`ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i img%06d.jpg output_video.mp4`

where `%06d` means the file name ends with 6 digits, change it to `%04d` is there are only 4 digits, etc. Set the framerate as low as you like. Can do many more things with it (crop, rotate and other image operations, overlay text or additional images, add sound tracks, etc.)

[MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy) is a Python module for video editing, it uses the same FFMpeg, among other things. IIRC, Python is installed by default in Ubuntu, installing MoviePy would take a second with `pip install moviepy`. A MoviePy version of the above command line would be something like this:

```
from glob import glob
from moviepy.editor import *

files = glob("*.jpg")
frames = [ImageClip(f, duration = 0.5) for f in files]
clip = concatenate_videoclips(frames, method = "compose")
clip.write_videofile("video.mp4", fps = 2)
```

Looks way more verbose for something as simple as converting a set of files into a video, but for more complex cases it might become more manageable than a long long long command line.

Comment: I can recommend the use of MoviePy (https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) as a front end for FFMPEG that makes this sort of thing a lot easier & more user friendly.

Comment: @Steve Barnes I wouldn't call it "more user friendly". Well, maybe "more Python programmer friendly", but even then it's probably an overkill for something as trivial as converting a set of jpegs into a video. It may worth it if you need some non-trivial processing or complicated visual effects, though.

Comment: If you call non-trivial processing adding a title page and a separator frame for each day or traversing sub-directories then yes. I also find the naming and the information available in the function helps a lot friendlier than the FFMPEG helps &  manuals.

Comment: OK, added a MoviePy example, let the reader judge for themselves.

Comment: Nice example, where it scores of course is getting it to recurse sub-directories is a simple change to the glob call and still cross platform. The same with direct use of `FFMPEG` tends to involve find and pipes IIRC and is not so platform independent.